# HTML Problema al implementar CSS externo

Tags: html, html5

Podrían ayudarme a corregir unos errores en una pagina web que estoy creando para un proyecto de clase.

Importe CSS de la pagina web de  Bootstrap que esta afectando partes de mi código que no quiero, además que al añadir los contenedores me esta resultando muy dificil corregir un problema estetico al cambiar el tamaño de la pestaña.

Los elementos que quiero corregir es:

1- El nav al pasar el ratón por encima se vuelve azul al haber importado CSS de otra pagina web.

2- No consigo separar el bloque de las Las Islas Frisias con el de Keukenhof al cambiar el tamaño de la ventana ya que se pegan los dos y queda muy feo.

Además me gustaría preguntar como podría copiar mi CSS y insertarlo en otras pestañas que estoy creando sin tener que escribirlo todo otra vez, para darle un toque más estético.

````
<!--Idioma-->
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!--Nombre de la web-->
    <title>HOLANDA</title>
    <!--Autor-->
    <meta name="author" content="Ana" />
    <!--Descripción-->
    <meta name="description" content="Página Web sobre Holanda" />
    <!--Adapta la página web a otras plataformas-->
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1"
    />
    <!--Palabras clave-->
    <meta name="keywords" content="Holanda, Inicio, Portal web, Índice" />
    <!--Bloquear rastreadores-->
    <meta name="robots" content="index" />
    <!-- Especificar la codificación de caracteres -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <!--Imagen del de la página web-->
    <!--Imagen favicon 16x16 -->
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="Favicon"
      href="https://cdn.glitch.me/d760ef3b-44cd-4fa5-b821-4c8708fc2936%2Ffavicon.ico?v=1634125626655"
      sizes="16x16"
    />

    <!--Imagen favicon 32x32 -->
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="Favicon"
      href="https://cdn.glitch.me/d760ef3b-44cd-4fa5-b821-4c8708fc2936%2Ffavicon.ico?v=1634125626655"
      sizes="32x32"
    />

    <!--Imagen favicon 64x64 -->
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="Favicon"
      href="https://cdn.glitch.me/d760ef3b-44cd-4fa5-b821-4c8708fc2936%2Ffavicon.ico?v=1634125626655"
      sizes="64x64"
    />
    <!--CSS externo -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!--Página web getbootstrap-->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/"
    />
    <style>
      ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      }

      li {
      float: left;
      }

      li a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      }

      li a:hover {
      background-color: #111;
      }
      body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #666;
      background: #F2FFE8;
      background-repeat: repeat-y;
      background-size: 10rem
      font-size: 1em;
      line-height: 1.5em;
      }

      h3 {
      font-size: 3em;
      line-height: 1em;
      margin: 15px 0;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: 1000;
      }
      img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      }
      #main-content {
      background: white;
      width: 90%;
      max-width: 800px;
      margin: 20px auto;
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      }

      #main-content header,
      #main-content .content {
      padding: 20px;
      }
      #main-footer {
      background: #333;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-top: 40px;
      }
      #main-footer p {
      margin: 0;
      }

      #main-footer a {
      color: white;
      }
         #logotipo {
        margin: -5px;
        t
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul class="tabs">
          <!--Barra de navegación-->
          <li>
            <!--Logotipo + título-->
            <div>
              <a
                href="https://holanda-pagina-web.glitch.me/Inicio.html"
                style="background-color:#7E3323;"
              >
                <img
                  id="logotipo"
                  src="https://cdn.glitch.me/d760ef3b-44cd-4fa5-b821-4c8708fc2936%2F616435.png?v=1634143591506"
                  width="27"
                  height="20"
                  alt="logotipo"
                />&nbsp; INICIO</a
              >
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://holanda-pagina-web.glitch.me/Holanda.html"
              >HOLANDA</a
            >
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://holanda-pagina-web.glitch.me/Tradiciones.html"
              >TRADICIONES</a
            >
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://holanda-pagina-web.glitch.me/Gastronomia.html"
              >GASTRONOMÍA</a
            >
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://holanda-pagina-web.glitch.me/Lugares.html"
              >LUGARES</a
            >
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://holanda-pagina-web.glitch.me/Formulario.html"
              >¿QUÉ SABES DE HOLANDA?</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <section id="main-content">
        <img
          src="https://cdn.glitch.me/d760ef3b-44cd-4fa5-b821-4c8708fc2936%2Frsz_1boudewijn-huysmans-hx_ygeb2evi-unsplash.jpg?v=1636549628999"
          alt="Portada"
        />
      </section>
      <!--Título de portada de la página web-->
      <h3>
        LUGARES
      </h3>
      <hr />
      <!-- ----------------------------------------------------------->

      <div class="container mt-5 mb-5 ">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- Lo que hace que esten una al lado de la otra -->
          <div class="col">
            <!-- Lo que hace que esten separadas-->
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; ">
              <!--Primera tarjeta-->
              <img
                src="https://cdn.glitch.me/55467325-304b-4388-a62a-5da1b2df9e7f%2Frsz_1alwin-kroon-kxqyfiin-qy-unsplash.jpg?v=1634037122843"
                class="card-img-top"
                alt="Molinos en un campo al lado del río"
              />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Molinos de viento de Kinderdijk</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Estos 19 preciosos molinos, declarados Patrimonio de la
                  Humanidad, forman la mayor concentración de antiguos molinos
                  de viento de los Países Bajos.
                </p>
                <center>
                  <a
                    href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WWj5QkmFlg"
                    target="_blank"
                  >
                    <input type="button" class="button" value="Ver video" />
                  </a>
                </center>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!------------------------------------------------------------------>

          <div class="col">
            <!-- Lo que hace que esten separadas-->
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <!--Segunda tarjeta-->
              <img
                src="https://cdn.glitch.me/55467325-304b-4388-a62a-5da1b2df9e7f%2Frsz_kira-laktionov-brdkh3ajan8-unsplash.jpg?v=1634038614193"
                class="card-img-top"
                alt="Molinos en un campo al lado del río"
              />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Las Islas Frisias</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Las cinco Islas Frisias holandesas (Texel, Terschelling,
                  Ameland, Vlieland y Schiermonnikoog), forman uno de los
                  paisajes más desconocidos y más increíbles que ver en Holanda.
                </p>
                <center>
                  <a
                    href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_W202S229g"
                    target="_blank"
                  >
                    <input type="button" class="button" value="Ver video" />
                  </a>
                </center>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!------------------------------------------------------------------>
          <div <div class="col">
            <!-- Lo que hace que esten separadas-->
            <div class="card " style="width: 18rem; ">
              <!--Tercera tarjeta-->
              <img
                src="https://cdn.glitch.me/55467325-304b-4388-a62a-5da1b2df9e7f%2Frsz_clemence-taillez-vgpspydnq7e-unsplash.jpg?v=1634038599119"
                class="card-img-top"
                alt="Molinos en un campo al lado del río"
              />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Keukenhof</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  En este gran parque de más de 32 hectáreas, cada primavera
                  florecen más de 7 millones de tulipanes que forman una
                  preciosa paleta de colores todos los años, también puedes
                  encontrar otras flores.
                </p>
                <center>
                  <a
                    href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jEXT3lD3OU"
                    target="_blank"
                  >
                    <input type="button" class="button" value="Ver video" />
                  </a>
                </center>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!------------------------------------------------------------------>
          <div class="col">
            <!-- Lo que hace que esten separadas-->
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <!--Cuarta tarjeta-->
              <img
                src="https://cdn.glitch.me/55467325-304b-4388-a62a-5da1b2df9e7f%2Frsz_sven-brandsma-bp4d8nzcsby-unsplash.jpg?v=1634072601360"
                class="card-img-top"
                alt="El Museo Municipal de Alkmaar"
              />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Alkmaar</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  En Alkmaar se celebra cada viernes entre las 10h y las 12:30h
                  de la mañana de abril a septiembre y el mercado de queso más
                  famoso. Además del famoso mercado también hay un museo.
                </p>
                <center>
                  <a
                    href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqcPPTxIUTA"
                    target="_blank"
                  >
                    <input type="button" class="button" value="Ver video" />
                  </a>
                </center>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <center>
        <!--Imagen casa para regreso a la pagina principal -->
        <a href="https://holanda-pagina-web.glitch.me/Inicio.html">
          <img
            src="https://cdn.glitch.me/d760ef3b-44cd-4fa5-b821-4c8708fc2936%2Fhouse-2374925_1280.png?v=1636408413875"
            alt="Imagen de una casa"
            width="50px"
            title="Inicio"
        /></a>
      </center>
    </header>
    <!--Pie de página-->
    <footer id="main-footer">
      <p>&copy; 2021 <a>Ana</a></p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Ana no hace falta que copies todo el style en cada página, crea archivos css i los llamas de esta manera `<link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

para los items del menu que se vuelvan de otro color seria de esta manera, que cambia todo el fondo del li

```
.tabs > li:hover {
   background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> me gustaría preguntar como podría copiar mi CSS y insertarlo en otras pestañas que estoy creando sin tener que escribirlo todo otra vez, para darle un toque más estético.

Puedes crear 'Hojas de estilos CSS', las cuales son archivos `.css` que contienen todas las clases que quieras meterle dentro.
Tal y como mencionan en la otra respuesta, puedes incluirlas usando:

```
<link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

En donde `href` es la ruta hasta la hoja de estilos. si la tienes dentro de una carpeta, debes darle la ruta de dicha carpeta. Esto lo puedes agregar en todos tus archivos `html` y asi mantener el mismo estilo en todas.
Recuerda siempre poner la hoja de estilos al final del resto, para que se aplique sobre el resto, es decir, si tienes bootstrap, y tu css, mantén ese mismo orden en el código.
[video de ejemplo](https://i.gyazo.com/93df1bb8910c1072339bbc8540a7fca1.mp4)

---

> 1- El nav al pasar el ratón por encima se vuelve azul al haber importado CSS de otra pagina web.

Esto tiene que ver con lo anteriormente mencionado.  Al traer un CSS externo, lo estás aplicando sobre tu propio CSS, por lo que se sobre-escribe. Si haces el tema de las hojas de estilo y las aplicas después de lo de bootstrap, deberías poder aplicar bien tus estilos. De todos modos, la mejor herramienta para evaluar el orden en el que se está aplicando todo, es (en Chrome) el DEV TOOLS, que es la pestaña que abres con F12. En la pestaña de 'elementos' podrás ver el código, y debajo, los estilos en el orden que se están aplicando, desde el ultimo aplicado, hasta el primero.

EDIT** Tu CSS está roto, por eso hay fallas, las menciono al final del texto.

---

> 2- No consigo separar el bloque de las Las Islas Frisias con el de Keukenhof al cambiar el tamaño de la ventana ya que se pegan los dos y queda muy feo.

Esta parte necesitaré que me expliques mejor el problema.
¿De que modo quieres separar los bloques?
¿Qué orden deberían llevar?

---

Por último, ¿Qué editor de código estás usando?. Tienes llaves mal cerradas en varias secciones, creo que un `<div <div class="col">` podría estar dando problemas a tu código. Mismo caso en el CSS, en el `body`, la parte de `background-size: 10rem font-size: 1em;`, te dará problemas al no estar correctamente cerrado, o esa `t` que está volando en el `#logotipo`. Un editor de texto bien adaptado podría indicarte estos errores de tipografía.

Comment: Gracias Excorpion trabajare en los puntos que me has remarcado para arreglar el código, y en respuesta a la plataforma donde trabajo es glitch.com (https://glitch.com/edit/#!/holanda-pagina-web). También en lo relacionadado al problema de los bloques, al ver la pagina web en una pestaña de navegador totalmente abierta queda bien pero al empezar a reducir el tamaño de la pestaña de navegador los bloques se adhieren unos con otros sin dejar espaciado. Lo que quiero es que cuando empiece a reducirla poder poner uno debajo del otro y que dejen un espaciado.